# Are properties in a Swift class automatically references?

Tags: swift, reference

I have this class in which the properties are the class itself.

```
class Voxel {
     var vertices : [Vertex] = []
     var above : Voxel?
     var below : Voxel?
     var front : Voxel?
     var back  : Voxel?
     var left  : Voxel?
     var right : Voxel?
}
```

It acts as a node in a Doubly 3D Linked List, but the thing is, in C and C++, I would have to store the neighbors as pointers (which I want to do to the vertex array as well).

Is this automatically done for me in Swift?

I don't see a fine way of holding an array of vertices as an array of pointers, and I certainly don't want to hold the actual values, as I'm going to have thousands of voxels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Voxel` is a `class`, a reference type, these are pointers. If it were a `struct`, it would be a value type and therefore each new reference would be a new copy.

By the way, be wary of strong reference cycles. Make sure one instance's implicit `strong` reference `below` is not another instance whose `above` is another `strong` reference back to the other instance. To resolve this, you'd make all of those references `weak` and then have some collection (e.g., a set or maybe an array or dictionary) which maintains strong references to all of the instances in the doubly linked list.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about the reference cycles, now I'm sure what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The defining characteristic of classes (vs. structs) is that they're reference types, and use reference semantics (i.e. assignment of an object only copies a reference to the object).

> **Classes Are Reference Types**
>
> Unlike value types, reference types are not copied when they are assigned to a variable or constant, or when they are passed to a function. Rather than a copy, a reference to the same existing instance is used instead.

Structs, on the other hand, are value types, and use value semantics (i.e. assignment of a struct copies it entirely).

> **Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types**
>
> A value type is a type whose value is copied when it is assigned to a variable or constant, or when it is passed to a function.

I suggest you give this a read: [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2)
 - Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)